# How to concat all columns of a table with different types with their values by identity in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I want to have a function to get `Table Name` and `Row ID` and return a `nvarchar` type, for example I have a table `A` like this:

```
TABLE A 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Active BIT NULL,
    Date DATE NULL
)
```

For example first row value is:

```
1,'jon',true,'06/08/2018'
```

This function should return this output:

```
ID:'1', Name:'jon', Active:'true', Date:'06/08/2018'
```

More explaining:
I have a log table that while a row is deleted from any other table,want to copy all columns with their values as text into log table as above.

Comment: Can you explain bit more?

Comment: i want select a Specified row by id that concatenate all column names with their values together as text just like i mentioned above.

Comment: is that concatenation should done in query?

Comment: yes, as I said, i want it in a function

Comment: You need to define your escaping rules: what do you want if name contains an apostrophe, e.g. "John O'Shea"?

Comment: in my language there is no apostrophe

Comment: @doomiyar, as per your edit, you should have a trigger to insert all rows deleted into the log table with the table name, id and rest of the columns required, so that it will come in handy for you to generate the required output

Comment: @doomiyar do you want this for number of rows or only for a single row? If multiple rows required, then what is the expected output?

Comment: @Biju jose, you are right if i want it for one table but i want use it dynamically for all database table.

Comment: @Selva TS, it's only for single row

Comment: @doomiyar Are you want Function or Stored Procedure? I can get this sorted out but it is not possible using function.

Comment: @SelvaTS, Function  is better but it can be Stored Procedure if function is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with comment,`UDF` is not work because the below query deals with `dynamic SQL`. Although I am not recommending this solution for longer run as this involves much dynamic queries.

The code is self explanatory. First get the columns converting into `NVARCHAR` and columns list. Then get the data unpivoting Column Name and Value. Then concatenate the result as desired.

Create a procedure like this,

```
CREATE PROC uspGetLogString(@TABLE VARCHAR(50), @ID INT)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @RETURNVALUE NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @WHERECLAUSE NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @ID)
    DECLARE @COLUMNSWITHTYPE NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @COLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT @COLUMNSWITHTYPE  = @COLUMNSWITHTYPE + 
        CASE 
            WHEN CL.DATA_TYPE = 'BIT' THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), CASE WHEN ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ' = 1 THEN ''True'' ELSE ''False'' END) AS ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ''
            WHEN CL.DATA_TYPE != 'NVARCHAR' THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ') AS ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + '' 
            ELSE CL.COLUMN_NAME 
        END  + ', ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CL WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE
    SELECT @COLUMNS  = @COLUMNS + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ', ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CL WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE

    SELECT @COLUMNSWITHTYPE = LEFT(@COLUMNSWITHTYPE, LEN(@COLUMNSWITHTYPE) - 1)
    SELECT @COLUMNS = LEFT(@COLUMNS, LEN(@COLUMNS) - 1)
    SELECT @COLUMNSWITHTYPE = 'SELECT ' + @COLUMNSWITHTYPE + ' FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE ' + @WHERECLAUSE

    DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT @DynamicSQL = 'DECLARE @RESULT NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''''
    SELECT @RESULT = @RESULT + TAB.COLUMN_NAME + '':'' + U.ColumnValue +'', ''
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS TAB
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue
            FROM (' +  @COLUMNSWITHTYPE + ')
            AS P
            UNPIVOT
            (
                ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (' + @COLUMNS + ' )
            ) as unpvt 
        )
         as U ON U.ColumnName = Tab.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE TAB.TABLE_NAME = ''' +  @TABLE + ''';
    SELECT @RESULT = LEFT(@RESULT, LEN(@RESULT) - 1)
    SELECT @RESULT
    '
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DynamicSQL, N'@OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT', @RETURNVALUE
END
GO
```

Then call it like,

```
EXEC dbo.uspGetLogString 'EMPLOYEE', 1
```

Comment: @SwlvaTS, Thanks, but there is some error when identity column not named as `ID`, and other error that say: `The type of column "blah blah" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list`

Comment: Finally I correct the errors  by finding `PRIMARY KEY` dynamically with some changes. thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since these things should be done in front-end or in your application layer still an answer I would suggest would be having an inline-table valued function for this. (note don't use a scalar function since it's not really a good performant.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.itvf_concata (
                                       @id INT
                                 )
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN SELECT 'ID:''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), id) 
              + ''''', Name:''''' + name 
              + ''''', Active:'''''
              + CASE
                      WHEN Active = 1 THEN 'TRUE' 
                      ELSE    'FALSE' 
                END 
              + ''''', Date:''''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date],101) + ''''
       FROM   a
       WHERE  id = @id;
```

Comment: what about `Table Name` ? I want it as parameter. and also the column names are changed while `Table Name` is parameter.

Comment: @doomiyar, you want a general query to query all tables with a table name as parameter?

Comment: The function I wrote only queries the table you mentioned as `"A"`

Comment: Ok, but at the first row I mentioned that 
I want to have a Function to get `Tabel Name` and `Row ID` and return a `nvarchar` type

Comment: Well the in the return statment you have mentioned like this `ID:'1', Name:'jon', Active:'true', Date:'06/08/2018'` and there is no table name here

Comment: Return statement is according to example, by the way ,do you have any solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `@Selva TS` answer to correct errors and finally get to this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SP_GetLogString (@TABLE VARCHAR(50), @ID INT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RETURNVALUE NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @PKey NVARCHAR(50) = (SELECT
  column_name AS PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU
  ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
  AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  AND KU.table_name = @TABLE)
DECLARE @WHERECLAUSE NVARCHAR(MAX) = @PKey + ' = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), 1000)
DECLARE @COLUMNSWITHTYPE NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @COLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT
@COLUMNSWITHTYPE = @COLUMNSWITHTYPE +
CASE
  WHEN CL.DATA_TYPE = 'BIT' THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), CASE WHEN ' +            CL.COLUMN_NAME + ' = 1 THEN ''True'' ELSE ''False'' END) AS ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ''
  WHEN CL.DATA_TYPE = 'float' THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), CONVERT(numeric,' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ')) AS ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ''
  ELSE 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ') AS ' + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ''
END + ', '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CL
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE
AND CL.DATA_TYPE <> 'image'
SELECT
@COLUMNS = @COLUMNS + CL.COLUMN_NAME + ', '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CL
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE
AND CL.DATA_TYPE <> 'image'

SELECT
 @COLUMNSWITHTYPE = LEFT(@COLUMNSWITHTYPE, LEN(@COLUMNSWITHTYPE) - 1)
SELECT
@COLUMNS = LEFT(@COLUMNS, LEN(@COLUMNS) - 1)
SELECT
@COLUMNSWITHTYPE = 'SELECT ' + @COLUMNSWITHTYPE + ' FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE ' +   @WHERECLAUSE

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT
@DynamicSQL = 'DECLARE @RESULT NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''''
SELECT @RESULT = @RESULT + TAB.COLUMN_NAME + '':'' + U.ColumnValue +'', ''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS TAB
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue
        FROM (' + @COLUMNSWITHTYPE + ')
        AS P
        UNPIVOT
        (
            ColumnValue FOR ColumnName IN (' + @COLUMNS + ' )
        ) as unpvt 
    )
     as U ON U.ColumnName = Tab.COLUMN_NAME
 WHERE TAB.TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE + ''' and TAB.DATA_TYPE<>''image'';
 SELECT @RESULT = LEFT(@RESULT, LEN(@RESULT) - 1)
   SELECT @RESULT'  EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @DynamicSQL  ,N'@OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX)OUT',@RETURNVALUE
END
GO
```